# Audio Framework Confusion

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, core-audio

I've read quite a bit both here ([Audio Framework in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067184/audio-framework-in-iphone)) and abroad but am still confused as to which Audio Framework to use.

I'm able to get some easier things done, like recording and playing back but I'm looking to the future of the app where I'll be doing more complex things, like managing past recordings (although maybe that's a `NSURL` bookmark thing) and editing audio.

Right now I'm using `AVFoundation` but have started reading the docs for Core Audio (and there's also AudioToolbox).  I wish there was a developer doc called "Understanding the Different Audio Frameworks and How and When to use them" because, well, the docs are dense and I'm having trouble figuring out which path to go down.

Links to good docs would also be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you [take a look](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0321636848) at the recent *Learning Core Audio* book. The purpose of it was to disambiguate the confusion around audio frameworks on Mac OS and iOS. If you want "good docs", it's well worth getting.

Depending on your requirements, you might also want to consider some of the non-Apple audio frameworks, particularly the [MoMu release of STK](http://momu.stanford.edu/stk/), which in may respects will be simpler and easier-to-use than Apple's frameworks.